# MSDTC is not supported by AWS RDS SQL server

Tags: http

I have transaction scope in my code which move transaction to MSDTC. But when I run this code into AWS cloud where RDS is SQL server. It is not supporting MSDTC please how can I make this supportable or what will be alternative way for this. I need MSDTC in my code.

Comment: please add some code samples.
what is the error you get?

Answer (score 0):

Well, there isn't much that you can do since AWS does not support it (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_SQLServer.html).

Features Not Supported and Features with Limited Support
The following Microsoft SQL Server features are not supported on Amazon RDS:

Stretch database
Backing up to Microsoft Azure Blob Storage
Buffer pool extension
Data Quality Services
Database Log Shipping
Database Mail
**Distribution Transaction Coordinator (MSDTC)**
File tables
FILESTREAM support
Maintenance Plans
Performance Data Collector
...
...

The alternative is to deploy/host/manage your own MSSQL server on AWS.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.SQLServer.Options.MSDTC.html

Looks like this is now supported by AWS.